# Datepicker atualizar as datas de acordo com retorno de um ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, data, datapicker

Eu quero exibir um calendário com somente algumas datas habilitadas, faço um requisição ajax que me retorna um array com as data que quero habilitar, a função que tenho hoje é parecido com esse exemplo [aqui no Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yXMKC/4/), so que os valores do array ***availableDates *** precisa ser passado no retono da requisição ajax, abaixo esta meu codigo.

```
//Função para modificar a agenda de acordo com o profissional
    $("#listaProfissionais").on('click', 'li a', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $.get("Agendamento/AgendaProfissional", { idFuncionario: id }, function (data) {

            availableDates = data;
            $("#calendario").css('display', 'block');
        });
    });


    $(function () {
        $("#calendario").datepicker({
            showOtherMonths: true,
            selectOtherMonths: true,
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Segunda', 'Terça', 'Quarta', 'Quinta', 'Sexta', 'Sábado'],
            dayNamesMin: ['D', 'S', 'T', 'Q', 'Q', 'S', 'S', 'D'],
            dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Seg', 'Ter', 'Qua', 'Qui', 'Sex', 'Sáb', 'Dom'],
            monthNames: ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro'],
            monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Out', 'Nov', 'Dez'],
            nextText: 'Proximo',
            prevText: 'Anterior',
            minDate: 0,
            beforeShowDay: available
        });
    });


    var availableDates;
    function available(date) {
        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
        if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
            return [true, "", "Available"];
        } else {
            return [false, "", "unAvailable"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: inclua o Html à sua pergunta

Comment: @LeandroAngelo consegui resolver, as datas que a requisição estava retornando estava separado por barra '"/" e a função estava tratando com tracinho "-"

Comment: Então acho que seria o caso de fechar essa pergunta